# XSL-FO format is off when printing pdf, but xsl-fo code appears okay? software: XML2PDF

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

[image]

I’m using XML2PDF to create badges for printing. Unfortunately I’m running into an issue where, when creating a new page (page-break-after=”always”), the next block-container is duplicated. This seems to happen when the block-container has a specified height. Without the height attribute the data looks okay (though I need to specify the heights).

I also noticed that increasing the page-height in simple-page-master also fixes this. I'm not sure why since the block-containers and margin don't go over the 11in height.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I'm missing any information

Note:

There are 6 badges per page. 2 columns and 3 rows. (each badge has a width of 4 inches and a height of 3 inches)

Each page has a footer that has a width of 4 inches and a height of 1.5 inches

```
  <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
 <fo:layout-master-set>
     <fo:simple-page-master master-name="badge" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in" margin-top="0.00in" margin-bottom="0.00in" margin-left="0.00in" margin-right="0.00in">
        <fo:region-body margin=".25in"/>
        <fo:region-before extent="0in"/>
        <fo:region-after extent="0in"/>
        <fo:region-start extent="0in"/>
        <fo:region-end extent="0in"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
 <fo:page-sequence master-reference="badge">
     <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:float float="left">
             <fo:block-container background-color="gray" height="3in" width="4in">
                <fo:block font-size="34px" font-weight="bold">Name - 1</fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="18px">Full Name</fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="18px">Company</fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="18px">City, State</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:float>
         <fo:float float="left">
             <fo:block-container background-color="gray" height="3in" width="4in">
                <fo:block font-size="34px" font-weight="bold">Name - 2</fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="18px">Full Name</fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="18px">Company</fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="18px">City, State</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:float>
        <fo:float clear="left"/>
         <fo:float float="left">
             <fo:block-container background-color="gray" height="3in" width="4in">
                <fo:block font-size="34px" font-weight="bold">Name - 3</fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="18px">FullName</fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="18px">Company</fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="18px">City, State</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:float>
         <fo:float float="left">
             <fo:block-container background-color="gray" height="3in" width="4in">
                <fo:block font-size="34px" font-weight="bold">Name - 4</fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="18px">Full Name</fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="18px">Company</fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="18px">City, State</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:float>
        <fo:float clear="left"/>
         <fo:float float="left">
             <fo:block-container background-color="gray" height="3in" width="4in">
                <fo:block font-size="34px" font-weight="bold">Name - 5</fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="18px">Full Name </fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="18px">Company</fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="18px">City, State</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:float>
         <fo:float float="left">
             <fo:block-container background-color="gray" height="3in" width="4in">
                <fo:block font-size="34px" font-weight="bold">Name - 6</fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="18px">Full Name</fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="18px"/>
                <fo:block font-size="18px">City, State</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:float>
        <fo:float clear="left"/>
         <fo:block-container background-color="gray" height="1.5in" width="8in" page-break-after="always">
            <fo:block> Text goes here </fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
         <fo:float float="left">
             <fo:block-container background-color="gray" height="3in" width="4in">
                <fo:block font-size="34px" font-weight="bold">Name - 7</fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="18px">Full Name</fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="18px">Company</fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="18px">City, State</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:float>
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

Comment: Without testing it, i would never use am empty fo float. Just put clear left on the next float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I understand your issue, are you saying that the block-container with "Text goes here" is thrown to the following page? While you "think" that the spacing all adds up, you are missing one thing in your mind. When you throw the fo:float, it has an inherent line height based on the default font. If you want this to fit perfectly, you need to set the line-height to "0" on the floats and then set it back to normal on the block-container inside. Your file as is is actually off by the line height of the first block. This formats to two pages (note I also removed the empty fo:float elements, that is technically an error to a formatter as a float cannot be empty and they are not needed).

(Tested with RenderX's formatter only, I do not have XML2PDF):

```
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="badge">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

            <fo:float float="left" line-height="0">
                <fo:block-container background-color="gray" height="3in" width="4in" line-height="normal">
                    <fo:block font-size="34px" font-weight="bold">Name - 1</fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="18px">Full Name</fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="18px">Company</fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="18px">City, State</fo:block>
                </fo:block-container>
            </fo:float>
            <fo:float float="left" line-height="0">
                <fo:block-container background-color="gray" height="3in" width="4in" line-height="normal">
                    <fo:block font-size="34px" font-weight="bold">Name - 2</fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="18px">Full Name</fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="18px">Company</fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="18px">City, State</fo:block>
                </fo:block-container>
            </fo:float>
            <fo:float float="left" line-height="0">
                <fo:block-container background-color="gray" height="3in" width="4in" line-height="normal">
                    <fo:block font-size="34px" font-weight="bold">Name - 3</fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="18px">FullName</fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="18px">Company</fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="18px">City, State</fo:block>
                </fo:block-container>
            </fo:float>
            <fo:float float="left" line-height="0">
                <fo:block-container background-color="gray" height="3in" width="4in" line-height="normal">
                    <fo:block font-size="34px" font-weight="bold">Name - 4</fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="18px">Full Name</fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="18px">Company</fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="18px">City, State</fo:block>
                </fo:block-container>
            </fo:float>
            <fo:float float="left" line-height="0">
                <fo:block-container background-color="gray" height="3in" width="4in" line-height="normal">
                    <fo:block font-size="34px" font-weight="bold">Name - 5</fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="18px">Full Name </fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="18px">Company</fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="18px">City, State</fo:block>
                </fo:block-container>
            </fo:float>
            <fo:float float="left" line-height="0">
                <fo:block-container background-color="gray" height="3in" width="4in" line-height="normal">
                    <fo:block font-size="34px" font-weight="bold">Name - 6</fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="18px">Full Name</fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="18px"/>
                    <fo:block font-size="18px">City, State</fo:block>
                </fo:block-container>
            </fo:float>
            <fo:block-container background-color="gray" height="1.3in" width="8in" page-break-after="always" clear="left">
                <fo:block> Text goes here </fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
            <fo:float float="left" line-height="0">
                <fo:block-container background-color="gray" height="3in" width="4in" line-height="normal">
                    <fo:block font-size="34px" font-weight="bold">Name - 7</fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="18px">Full Name</fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="18px">Company</fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="18px">City, State</fo:block>
                </fo:block-container>
            </fo:float>

        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
```

[image: PDF Result]

Comment: Kevin - thanks for taking a stab at my issue. I've attached a screenshot of your xsl-fo code rendered with XML2PDF. line-heights and floats are supported (http://www.alt-soft.com/index/support/conformance-list/xsl-fo-conformance-list/)

Comment: "supported" is what they say. you ccan run that sample with RenderX XEP and you get the 100% correct answer. Sorry I can't help with that.

Comment: Can I assume that XML2PDF interprets xsl-fo data differently than Render X? Also, you had asked if the issue was "text goes here" appeared on the second page. This was not the case - the badge "Name - 7" would appear twice on the 2nd page. This seemed odd since my original code only listed it once. The only way to fix this was to increase the page-height.

Comment: I guess that answers it. I've been banging my head wondering why it does not work. I've been clearing the floats because the badges went off the page... instead of floating left to right - top to bottom. Thanks for the quick responses. Given that the number of badges will change - is there anything else i could try that would be quick to implement like floats?

Comment: Yes, that would be completely wrong. There is nothing in your XSL FO (or anyone's for that matter) that would cause something to be rendered twice. As for qualities, you can assume what you wish. AFAIK, RenderX is the gold standard for what should be. And with that file, it renders (I believe) exactly what you want (and expect).

Comment: Anything else? You could put each in a table-cell and use "ends-row" attribute after each two. See this answer I gave previoously to a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24311352/xslt-xsl-fo-creating-a-table-with-multiple-rows/24319310#24319310

Comment: Thanks again Kevin. Closing this topic as an issue with XML2PDF - not the code  - based on your responses.