# Displaying images in a grid with XSL-FO

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, xmltype

```
<xsl:template match="PrintingImages">
<fo:block keep-together.within-page="always">
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-collapse="separate" border-separation="2pt" column-width="50pt">
        <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

```
<xsl:template match='PrintImagesData'>
   <fo:table-cell>
   <fo:block keep-together.within-page="always" float="left">
       <xsl:if test="Title">
           <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="Title" /></fo:block>
       </xsl:if>
       <xsl:if test="DateCreated">
           <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="DateCreated" /></fo:block>
       </xsl:if>
       <fo:block line-stacking-strategy="max-height">
           <xsl:element name="fo:external-graphic">
               <xsl:attribute name="width"><xsl:value-of select="Width"/></xsl:attribute>
               <xsl:attribute name="height"><xsl:value-of select="Height"/></xsl:attribute>
               <xsl:attribute name="content-width">scale-down-to-fit</xsl:attribute>
               <xsl:attribute name="content-height">scale-down-to-fit</xsl:attribute>
               <xsl:attribute name="scaling">uniform</xsl:attribute>
               <xsl:attribute name="src">url('<xsl:value-of select="ImgData"/>')</xsl:attribute>
           </xsl:element>
       </fo:block>
   </fo:block>
```

On the backend I call `PrintImagesData` 4 times, and within the PDF, it generates four images on the same line. I want two images on each line (e.g. two rows, two columns). How can I do that?

Comment: Can you provide us with the input XML, and more of your XSLT? It seems you don't insert several `<fo:table-row>`

Comment: If you are using a renderer that supports floats then use floats. They would stack two per line if sized correctly. There is no need for a table.

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24311352/xslt-xsl-fo-creating-a-table-with-multiple-rows. This is an alternate to the answer below where you do not needs to throw rows for the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a new `fo:table-row` at every odd positioned `PrintImagesData` and then create an `fo:table-cell` for that `PrintImagesData` and the first following-sibling `PrintImagesData`.

Here's an example based on the limited amount of info in the original question...

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <PrintingImages>
        <PrintImagesData>
            <Title>Title 1</Title>
            <Width>100px</Width>
            <Height>100px</Height>
            <ImgData>some/graphic1.png</ImgData>
        </PrintImagesData>
        <PrintImagesData>
            <Title>Title 2</Title>
            <Width>100px</Width>
            <Height>100px</Height>
            <ImgData>some/graphic2.png</ImgData>
        </PrintImagesData>
        <PrintImagesData>
            <Title>Title 3</Title>
            <Width>100px</Width>
            <Height>100px</Height>
            <ImgData>some/graphic3.png</ImgData>
        </PrintImagesData>
        <PrintImagesData>
            <Title>Title 4</Title>
            <Width>100px</Width>
            <Height>100px</Height>
            <ImgData>some/graphic4.png</ImgData>
        </PrintImagesData>
    </PrintingImages>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0** (Made a couple of changes to your original XSLT; mainly the use of [AVT's](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates).)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
                    <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body"> 
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PrintingImages">
        <fo:block keep-together.within-page="always">
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-collapse="separate" border-separation="2pt" column-width="50pt">
                <fo:table-body>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="PrintImagesData[not(position() mod 2 = 0)]" mode="row"/>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PrintImagesData" mode="row">
        <xsl:variable name="nbr">
            <xsl:number/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <fo:table-row>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="not($nbr mod 2 = 0)">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="following-sibling::PrintImagesData">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::PrintImagesData[1]"/>                        
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block/>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:if>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PrintImagesData">
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block keep-together.within-page="always" float="left">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Title|DateCreated"/>
                <fo:block line-stacking-strategy="max-height">
                    <fo:external-graphic 
                        width="{Width}" 
                        height="{Height}" 
                        content-width="scale-down-to-fit"
                        content-height="scale-down-to-fit" 
                        scaling="uniform" 
                        src="url('{ImgData}')"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Title|DateCreated">
        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSL-FO Output**

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
         <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:block keep-together.within-page="always">
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-collapse="separate" border-separation="2pt" column-width="50pt">
               <fo:table-body>
                  <fo:table-row>
                     <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block keep-together.within-page="always" float="left">
                           <fo:block>Title 1</fo:block>
                           <fo:block line-stacking-strategy="max-height">
                              <fo:external-graphic width="100px" height="100px" content-width="scale-down-to-fit" content-height="scale-down-to-fit" scaling="uniform" src="url('some/graphic1.png')"/>
                           </fo:block>
                        </fo:block>
                     </fo:table-cell>
                     <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block keep-together.within-page="always" float="left">
                           <fo:block>Title 2</fo:block>
                           <fo:block line-stacking-strategy="max-height">
                              <fo:external-graphic width="100px" height="100px" content-width="scale-down-to-fit" content-height="scale-down-to-fit" scaling="uniform" src="url('some/graphic2.png')"/>
                           </fo:block>
                        </fo:block>
                     </fo:table-cell>
                  </fo:table-row>
                  <fo:table-row>
                     <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block keep-together.within-page="always" float="left">
                           <fo:block>Title 3</fo:block>
                           <fo:block line-stacking-strategy="max-height">
                              <fo:external-graphic width="100px" height="100px" content-width="scale-down-to-fit" content-height="scale-down-to-fit" scaling="uniform" src="url('some/graphic3.png')"/>
                           </fo:block>
                        </fo:block>
                     </fo:table-cell>
                     <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block keep-together.within-page="always" float="left">
                           <fo:block>Title 4</fo:block>
                           <fo:block line-stacking-strategy="max-height">
                              <fo:external-graphic width="100px" height="100px" content-width="scale-down-to-fit" content-height="scale-down-to-fit" scaling="uniform" src="url('some/graphic4.png')"/>
                           </fo:block>
                        </fo:block>
                     </fo:table-cell>
                  </fo:table-row>
               </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
         </fo:block>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, i  use a loop to get all the images, so the images could be more than 4.(maybe 30)  Is there an other way to do that ?

Comment: @HellGuoan - You should be able to do the same thing with a loop. Also, my answer should handle more than 4 images. (I did update it though so an empty cell is output if there are an odd number of `PrintImagesData`.) Is there a reason you can't change the loop to an `xsl:apply-templates`? You should update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I can't express my mood, but thank you very very much! That is really helpful. I appreciate your time and patient!