# Display XML in a grid (Seen from W3 school)

Tags: xml, xslt, html-table

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h1>Music Collection:</h1>
<table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th>Title</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table> 
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Those codes come from W3 school, i just made a few changes. im looking for a way to put those "Titles" into a 6*6 grid?(like 6rows, 6 columns) How to do that....

ps:http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=tryxsl_for-each here is the link for testing..

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking.  Could you please re-word or add more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really shouldn't be any reason to use `xsl:for-each`; but since it seems like [you are specifically looking for a for-each solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258352/displaying-images-in-a-grid-with-xsl-fo/29259547?noredirect=1#comment46722637_29259547), here's an example.

**XML Input**

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Still got the blues</title>
        <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Virgin records</company>
        <price>10.20</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Eros</title>
        <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>BMG</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1997</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>One night only</title>
        <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Polydor</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1998</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Sylvias Mother</title>
        <artist>Dr.Hook</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS</company>
        <price>8.10</price>
        <year>1973</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Maggie May</title>
        <artist>Rod Stewart</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Pickwick</company>
        <price>8.50</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Romanza</title>
        <artist>Andrea Bocelli</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>Polydor</company>
        <price>10.80</price>
        <year>1996</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>When a man loves a woman</title>
        <artist>Percy Sledge</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Atlantic</company>
        <price>8.70</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Black angel</title>
        <artist>Savage Rose</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>Mega</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1995</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>1999 Grammy Nominees</title>
        <artist>Many</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Grammy</company>
        <price>10.20</price>
        <year>1999</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>For the good times</title>
        <artist>Kenny Rogers</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Mucik Master</company>
        <price>8.70</price>
        <year>1995</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Big Willie style</title>
        <artist>Will Smith</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1997</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Tupelo Honey</title>
        <artist>Van Morrison</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Polydor</company>
        <price>8.20</price>
        <year>1971</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Soulsville</title>
        <artist>Jorn Hoel</artist>
        <country>Norway</country>
        <company>WEA</company>
        <price>7.90</price>
        <year>1996</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>The very best of</title>
        <artist>Cat Stevens</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Island</company>
        <price>8.90</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Stop</title>
        <artist>Sam Brown</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>A and M</company>
        <price>8.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Bridge of Spies</title>
        <artist>T`Pau</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Siren</company>
        <price>7.90</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Private Dancer</title>
        <artist>Tina Turner</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Capitol</company>
        <price>8.90</price>
        <year>1983</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Midt om natten</title>
        <artist>Kim Larsen</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>Medley</company>
        <price>7.80</price>
        <year>1983</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Pavarotti Gala Concert</title>
        <artist>Luciano Pavarotti</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>DECCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1991</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>The dock of the bay</title>
        <artist>Otis Redding</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Atlantic</company>
        <price>7.90</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Picture book</title>
        <artist>Simply Red</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>Elektra</company>
        <price>7.20</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Red</title>
        <artist>The Communards</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>London</company>
        <price>7.80</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Unchain my heart</title>
        <artist>Joe Cocker</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>EMI</company>
        <price>8.20</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="groupBy" select="6"/>

    <xsl:template match="/catalog">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Music Collection:</h1>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th colspan="{$groupBy}">Title</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="cd[position() mod $groupBy = 1]">
                        <tr>
                            <xsl:for-each select="title">
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>                                
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::cd[$groupBy > position()]">
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            <xsl:if test="$groupBy > count(following-sibling::cd[position() mod $groupBy = 1]) and
                                $groupBy - count(following-sibling::cd[$groupBy > position()])-1 > 0">
                                <td colspan="{$groupBy - count(following-sibling::cd[$groupBy > position()])-1}">&#8203;</td>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>                    
                </table> 
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>Music Collection:</h1>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th colspan="6">Title</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Empire Burlesque</td>
            <td>Hide your heart</td>
            <td>Greatest Hits</td>
            <td>Still got the blues</td>
            <td>Eros</td>
            <td>One night only</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Sylvias Mother</td>
            <td>Maggie May</td>
            <td>Romanza</td>
            <td>When a man loves a woman</td>
            <td>Black angel</td>
            <td>1999 Grammy Nominees</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>For the good times</td>
            <td>Big Willie style</td>
            <td>Tupelo Honey</td>
            <td>Soulsville</td>
            <td>The very best of</td>
            <td>Stop</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Bridge of Spies</td>
            <td>Private Dancer</td>
            <td>Midt om natten</td>
            <td>Pavarotti Gala Concert</td>
            <td>The dock of the bay</td>
            <td>Picture book</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Red</td>
            <td>Unchain my heart</td>
            <td colspan="4">&#8203;</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Alternate example location (way better than w3schools.com): http://xsltransform.net/bdxtqj